# Перевод float в int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Имеется фрейм `a*b`. Фрейм состоит их `float`, `object`, `int`. Есть объекты `NaN`.
Под "а" в том числе идет нумерация.
Соответственно "b" определяют наименования колонок.
Каким конструктом перевести ВСЕ `float` переменные фрейма в `int`, при этом НЕ удаляя ячеек ?

Comment: `df = df.astype(int)` ?

Comment: Поправил описание. В фрейме есть также object.
Дает :
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'некоторый текст'

Comment: `df = df.astype(int, errors='ignore')`

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста для NaN включений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два способа. Разница в колонке №4.

```
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(itr.combinations([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 'a', 'b'], 6))

print(df.astype(int, errors='ignore'))
print()
print(df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x))

   0  1  2  3    4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5.5  a
1  1  2  3  4  5.5  b
2  1  2  3  4    a  b
3  1  2  3  5    a  b
4  1  2  4  5    a  b
5  1  3  4  5    a  b
6  2  3  4  5    a  b

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  a
1  1  2  3  4  5  b
2  1  2  3  4  a  b
3  1  2  3  5  a  b
4  1  2  4  5  a  b
5  1  3  4  5  a  b
6  2  3  4  5  a  b
```

`NaN` имеет тип `float64`. Чтобы получить `int` можно пойти двумя путями.

1. Конвертировать столбец в `int64`.
2. Конвертировать `NaN` в число типа `int`.

Пример:

```
import itertools as itr
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(itr.combinations([2.2, 3.3, pd.np.NaN, 4.4, 5.5, 'a', 'b'], 6))

print(df.applymap(
    lambda x: int(x) if not pd.isna(x) and isinstance(x, float) else x
).astype({1: pd.Int64Dtype(), 2: 'Int64'}))
print()
print(df.fillna(0).applymap(lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x))

   0    1    2  3  4  5
0  2    3  NaN  4  5  a
1  2    3  NaN  4  5  b
2  2    3  NaN  4  a  b
3  2    3  NaN  5  a  b
4  2    3    4  5  a  b
5  2  NaN    4  5  a  b
6  3  NaN    4  5  a  b

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  2  3  0  4  5  a
1  2  3  0  4  5  b
2  2  3  0  4  a  b
3  2  3  0  5  a  b
4  2  3  4  5  a  b
5  2  0  4  5  a  b
6  3  0  4  5  a  b
```

Answer (score 0):

То, что подошло:

```
df_test.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df_test = df_test.astype(int, errors='ignore')
```